# How create a function to read string to structure?

Tags: c

I want to create a function that read the string dynamically allocated with C,but the program read togher the two field of struct. T_magazzino nuova struttura create the dynamically allocated and char *s_gets read the string

```
char * s_gets(char * st, int n)
{
   char * ret_val;
   char * find;

   ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);

   if (ret_val)
   {
      find = strchr(st, '\n'); // look for newline
      if (find) // if the address is not NULL,
         *find = '\0'; // place a null character there
      else
         while (getchar() != '\n')
           continue; // dispose of rest of line
   }
   return ret_val;
}

t_magazzino *nuova_struttura(void)
{
   t_magazzino *a;
   a=(t_magazzino*)malloc(sizeof(t_magazzino));
   if(a==NULL)
   {
      puts("Errore");
      exit(1);
   }

void item(t_magazzino *a, FILE *f,int c)
{
   puts("Inserisci ID");
   scanf("%d",&a->id);
   puts("Inserisci cliente \n");
  scanf("%s",a->client);
   printf(" Inserire tipologia \n");
 scanf("%s",a->tiplogia);
}
```

Comment: You should fix the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `nuova_struttura` have to return something, and have to finish with `}`

Comment: Bad to mix `scanf("%d"...` with `fgets()`.  Read the ID with `char buf[80]; s_gets(buf,...)` and then use `sscanf(buf, "%d",&a->id)`

Comment: How do I replace the code ?

Comment: ok,so the program doesn't work with fgets function.